# Selecting the largest from sets of duplicates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

I have a poly line layer where each feature has a Geometric Length and numerical ID. Some of these IDs are duplicates. I would like to be able to select the longest line from each set of duplicates to create a new layer with just the unique IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS 2.18 case:

1. Open attribute table
2. Activate `Select by expression`
3. Type `$length = maximum($length, group_by:= "id")`
4. Click on [Select]
5. `Save As...` (Save only selected features)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about 'group_by'.

Comment: Thanks @SteveH , Yes  `Aggregates` group is relatively new [Changelog for QGIS 2.16](http://www.qgis.org/ru/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-aggregate-support-for-expressions). I think they are extremely useful.